# Can a ground loop occur if everything is sharing a single socket?

Tags: ground, grounding, ground-loop

In a system where all devices that are connected ultimately share the same wall-socket, is it possible for a ground loop to occur.

For example:

A strip cable plugged into a socket powers a computer and an audio interface. There is a guitar connected to the interface via the patchbay using TR cables.

Assume nothing else is plugged into the strip plug or into the sam socket.

Theoretically could a ground loop occur and effect the audio signal? And if so, how would that happen. My understanding is that a ground loop occurs when there is more than one route to ground, and in the example above there is only one socket, and therefore only one route.

Comment: Theoretically yes. But it's not like it's much different with two sockets.

Comment: My understanding of ground loops is that they occur when there are two (or more) different grounds, or routes to ground. In the case of a single socket, there is only a single ground so it feels like a ground loop shouldn't be possible.

Comment: I've expanded my question to include my assumptions.

Comment: Is the audio interface connected to PC? If yes, and if audio interface power supply is grounded to mains strip and PC is grounded to mains strip then there is a loop between those three devices. Please bear in mind we have no clue what kind of power supplies or mains inlets you PC or audio interface has, or connections between PC and audio interface.

Comment: You're drawing arbitrary boundaries in the circuit when there are none. If what you said was true you would *never* have to worry in a battery or generator powered circuit.

Comment: OK. I think my understanding of ground loops is well wide of the mark.

Comment: Think antenna, both transmission and reception.

Comment: Please update the question with all connections to answer it. For example, computer plugged to wall by itself, no loop. Monitor plugged to wall by itself, no loop. Connect monitor to PC, and you have a ground loop already, from wall socket to PC to monitor to wall socket.

Answer (score 3):

Don't get fixated on what *you* call ground and what *I* call earth - earth (ground in your words) isn't the issue here because, all your audio equipment could be isolated from earth and you can still get audio interference due to inadequate grounding star-points. Here, I'm referring to ground as the audio/analogue signal return path and not earth (as in safety earth or earth rods).

I'm also trying to say that any ground wire (not earth) that is used to convey power to an amplifier circuit **must not** share the same ground connection as those used to transfer audio/analogue signals. Hence, why I mentioned star-pointing earlier.

What the term "ground loops" refers to is not a connection to earth but a loop in the signal and power grounds whereby the signal ground is contaminated with power currents and thus causes small interfering voltages to be added to the signal. These get amplified along with the signal and you get a 5h1tty sound. This happens where there is a loop in the connected grounds.

Star-pointing is used to keep power grounds and signal grounds separated within the audio system. They do connect but at one point only. Hence this technique avoids ground loops.

> *My understanding is that a ground loop occurs when there is more than
> one route to ground*

It's got nothing to do with what I call earth and what you appear to be calling ground. It's got everything to do with power currents sharing the same wires as signal currents and affecting the signal voltages.

Answer (score 2):

Ground is simply where you define 0V.

This is true for a floating battery or mobile or a noisy DC-DC supply or the PE protective Earth ground pin or tower case.

Protective earth is the connected to earth ground at some point, so for the intent of safety with Neutral also grounded at source.

Often any of these can be called "ground".

A "ground loop" occurs when there are multiple ground or signal return paths.  This can become a problem when the signal is path is shared by unwanted noise currents.

However line 'hum" can also be picked up by high impedance low level signals when powered  by DC-DC supplies from the common-mode RF carrier noise of the switched-mode power supplies that are modulated by AC line current noise modulated AC to DC.

The objective is to distribute a signal and its return path so that what is received is the same as what was sent.

If there is noise added, it can either be conducted thru a shared ground or "ground loop" or radiated and absorbed by mismatched impedances for the signal and return path in which case a shield is helpful terminated only at the source so that no shared currents can be conducted.

To resolve a line hum issue, sketch the path of all PE connections, shields and what you think are AC ground vs floating DC grounds.  Use a DMM to check.